# How can I re-write this loop as a closure?

Tags: rust, functional-programming

```rs
let mut result = some_func();
for s in some_iterator {
    if result.is_ok() {
        break;
    }
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
    result = some_func();
}
// use result
```

I have a code that looks like above, retrying to call `some_func()`. Here, I have to declare `result` as `mut` to update it during the retry. Is there some functional magic that I can use so that I do not have to declare `result` as `mut`?

I thought about the following, but do not think it is an ideal example, since I will have to iterate over each element of `some_iterator` there, which is not what I want

```rust
let result = some_iterator.fold(some_func(), |result, x| {
    if result.is_ok() {
        return result; 
    }
    // sleep and retry 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. It's much harder to adapt such code to changing requirements, like "add an overall timeout", "add a maximum retry count", "abort on non-retryable errors", or "do exponential backoff".

Instead, create a proper `RetryStrategy` abstraction that you just give the "fetch" closure and maybe a "is error fatal" closure. Better, use one that already exists, like maybe the [`retry`](https://docs.rs/retry/latest/retry/) or [`backoff`](https://docs.rs/backoff/latest/backoff/) crate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold), but this requires swapping the `Ok` and `Err` variants of the `Result`:

```
trait<T, E> SwappedExt<T, E> {
    fn swap_result (self) -> Result<E, T>;
}

impl<T, E> SwappedExt<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn swap_result (self) -> Result<E, T> {
        match self {
            Ok (x) -> Err (x),
            Err (e) -> Ok (e),
        }
    }
}

let result = some_func().or_else (|e|
    some_iterator.try_fold (e, |_, _| {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        some_func().swap_result()
    }).swap_result());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```rs
retry_strategy.map(
    |_|some_func()
).skip_while(
    |i|if i.is_err(){
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
).next().unwrap().unwrap()
```